# How to achieve mutual recursion to avoid names not being defined?

Tags: clojure, functional-programming, mutual-recursion

I've a clojure program in which two function recursively call each other:

```
(defn f1
...
(f2 ...)
)


(defn f2
...
(f1 ...)
)
```

The compiler is giving an error in `f1`. It's saying that f2 isn't defined. Is there a way to `declare` a function in clojure. I can verify that the recursion actually terminates.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Mutually recursive definitions in Clojure](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3213405/mutually-recursive-definitions-in-clojure)

Answer (score 9):

Literally [`declare`](https://clojuredocs.org/clojure.core/declare):

```
(declare f2)
(defn f1 []
  (f2))

(defn f2 []
  (f1))
```

Answer (score 2):

there is also a `letfn` form for (possibly) mutually recursive functions:

```
user=> (letfn [(f1 [x] (if (< x 10) (f2 x) x))
               (f2 [x] (f1 (inc x)))]
         (f2 0))

;;=> 10
```

**update**
if you then need these functions globally, you can always use `def` inside `letfn`. As for me i find this approach to be a bit cleaner, than `declare` (especially for mutually recursive ones):

```
user> (letfn [(f1 [x] (if (< x 10) (f2 x) x))
              (f2 [x] (f1 (inc x)))]
        (def f1 f1)
        (def f2 f2))
#'user/f2

user> (f2 0)
;;=> 10
```

Comment: Interesting. I didn't know `letfn` allowed this. Of course though, this only works if defining the functions locally is sufficient.

Comment: @Carcigenicate, well you can always use `def` inside `letfn`. I do it sometimes to emphasize that these functions are connected. Updated my answer.